# Loop is not working as it should

Tags: bash, shell-script

Am i missing something, because this loop sometimes is not working as it should?

```
#!/bin/bash

Data="/path/to/data.txt"
while true
do
    if [ -f "$Data" ]; then
        rows=$(tail -n +1 "$Data" | wc -l)
            if [ "$rows" = 0 ]; then
                    rm "$Data"
                else
                        line=$(sed -e 1p $Data);
                        IFS=', ' read -a array <<< "$line";
                        exec > >(tee /var/www/report.txt) 2>&1
                        bash -c "/path/to/program.sh -i ${array[0]} -p ${array[1]} -r ${array[2]} -t ${array[3]}" | rm "$Data"
            fi
    fi
   sleep 1
done
```

Purpose of infinity loop is because i am using it as background process when i call this script.

Comment: What, exactly, is the loop supposed to do that it currently doesn't do?

Comment: This script capture data from $Data when $Data -text file exists and then passes parameters to program.sh. Sometimes it works fine but all the suddenly in the next turn of loop it turns out like there is no data passed to program.sh like it was removed before it was readed that $Data. Keep in mind that $Data is continuously created by another program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, some process is overwriting the file you named `$Data`, and you're trying to call a command on any new contents that appear. The code you posted has a race condition, in that time passes between the tail-wc test and the line extraction with sed.

I would recommend altering the requirements so that:

- The writing script appends lines to the file, rather than overwriting it, and
- The reading script uses tail to read newly-written lines; you could use     something like `tail -f "$Data" | while read ...`.